# Responsive Table design Issue

Tags: jsp, css, responsive-design, jsp-tags, displaytag

I want to show a table as responsive in jsp.

I am using a displaytag for displaying the table and for pagination.

While I tried to make it responsive, I followed the steps in 
http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/
and done it. But the name in the `<thead>` tag differ from the table in the responsive.

He also explain to use

```
<td data-label="First name">Chris</td>

td:before { content: attr(data-label); }
```

To make content stays in HTML not in CSS.

But when I used it in the jsp it shows the warning as

Undefined attribute name `data-title` and Undefined attribute name `data-label`

inside the `<display:column>` tag.

Please suggest me any other way to declare the "data-title or data-label" attribute in the `<display:column>` tag.

Comment: It does not look like displaytable gives you the option to set arbitrary attributes in a `TD` element. It's not hard to write out your own HTML table using `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: Hi Macmade,
Thanks for your quick reply.
Can you please explain briefly how can we use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<display:table>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here is one way to add `data-label` attributes to your `<td>` elements using plain old core JSTL.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="person" items="people">
        <tr>
            <td data-label="First name"><c:out value="person.firstName" /></td>
            <td data-label="Last name"><c:out value="person.lastName" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** this does not use the displaytable library.